# yui3 fire function when form's checkboxes changes

Tags: yui, yui3

Say we have a yui3 form:

```
YUI().use("gallery-form", function (Y) {
var checkbox = new Y.CheckboxField({
    name : "myCheckbox",
    value : "check",
    label : "Test Checkbox"
});

var f = new Y.Form({
    boundingBox: '#form',
    action : 'test.php',
    method : 'post',
    children : [
        checkbox ,
        {name : 'submitBtn', type : 'SubmitButton', value : 'Submit'}
    ]
});

f.render();
});
```

I.e. form has a lot of checkboxes; I would like every checkboxes on this form to `onchange="fn(this)"`.
[Here's a small example of what i need.](http://jsfiddle.net/93hmB/)

**NB**. `checkbox` in the second line shouldn't be modify. I'm looking for something like:

```
form.all('input type=checkbox').on('change', fn(checkbox));
```

_

```
// where fn is:
function fn(el){ console.log(el.checked); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is kind of criptic. I think the expected way is to do `form.on('*:change', fn)` and filter the event propagation, but I can't find a way to avoid duplicate calls to the callback.

So you can resort to the Form's `change` UI event and do:

```
form.on('change', function (e) {
  var checkbox = e.domEvent.target;
  console.log(checkbox.get('checked'));
});
```

Comment: it also needs extra validation for checkboxes, e.g. `if(checkbox.get('type') == 'checkbox')` in case there's not only checkboxes in the form; P.S. Nevertheless it can serve as the solution, thanks;